# Flow cannot resolve pdf file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, flowtype

I have a problem: I'm importing a pdf file with webpack file-loader, and it works find, but Flow gives me

> InferError: Cannot resolve module './userAgreement.pdf'

I already declared pdf extension in my `.flowconfig` and created a `FileStub`:

```
module.name_mapper='\.\(pdf|png|jpe?g|gif|svg\)$' -> 'FileStub'
declare module 'FileStub' {
  declare export default string;
}
```

But it's not helping. What else can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Can you try adding a \ before each | character? I think that's the correct syntax according to the [OCaml regex docs](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html).